# Stitching multiple pngs into a h5 image h5py

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, h5py

I created an model in blender. From here I took 2d slices through the y-plane of that model leading to the following.

600 png files each corresponding to a ylocation i.e y=0, y=0.1 etc
Each png file has a resolution of 500 x 600.

I am now trying to merge the 600 pngs into a h5 file using python before loading the .h5 into some software. I find that each individual png file is read fine and looks great. However when I look at the final 3d image there is some stretching of the image, and im not sure how this is being created.

The images are resized (from 600x600 to 500x600, but I have checked and this is not the cause of the stretching). I would like to know why I am introducing such stretching in other planes (not y-plane).

Here is my code, please note that there is some work in progress here, hence why I append the dataset to a list (this is to be used for later code)

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np
import cv2 
from datetime import datetime
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(dir_path + '//..//..')

Xlen=500
Ylen=600
Zlen=600

directory=dir_path+"/LowPolyA21/"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.png'):
        image = Image.open(directory+filename)
        new_image = image.resize((Zlen, Xlen))
        new_image.save(directory+filename)

dataset = np.zeros((Xlen, Zlen, Ylen), np.float)

# traverse all the pictures under the specified address
cnt_num = 0
img_list = sorted(os.listdir(directory))
os.chdir(directory)

for img in (img_list):
    if img.endswith(".png"):
        gray_img = cv2.imread(img, 0)
        dataset[:, :, cnt_num] = gray_img
        cnt_num += 1

dataset[dataset == 0] = -1

dataset=dataset.swapaxes(1,2)

datasetlist=[]
datasetlist.append(dataset)

dz_dy_dz = (float(0.001),float(0.001),float(0.001))
for j in range(Xlen):
    for k in range(Ylen):
        for l in range(Zlen):
            if datasetlist[i][j,k,l]>1:
                datasetlist[i][j,k,l]=1
    
now = datetime.now()
timestamp = now.strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M%S%f")
out_h5_path='voxelA_'+timestamp+'_flipped'
out_h5_path2='voxelA_'+timestamp+'_flipped.h5'
with h5py.File(out_h5_path2, 'w') as f:
    f.attrs['dx_dy_dz'] = dz_dy_dz
    f['data'] = datasetlist[i] # Write data to the file's primary key data below
```

Example of image without stretching (in y-plane)

[image]

Example of image with stretching (in x-plane)

[image]

Comment: Saving a image as H5 data will not modify the data. Something odd occurs in your process. You need to test each step: 1) read 1 image (w/out resizing), save to h5, retrieve and plot. 2) read 1 image, resize, save to h5, retrieve and plot. 3) read 10 images (w/out resizing), save to h5, retrieve and plot. 4) read 10 images, resize, save to h5, retrieve and plot. A test that fails should identify the culprit. BTW, you said "_images are resized to 500x600_" but your code is `image.resize((Zlen, Xlen))` with `Zlen=600, Xlen=500`.

Comment: Thanks, Ill look at this over the evening. Apologies, the code is correct, the axis got confused in the transition from blender but the axis info in the code is correct